# Immediate function using JavaScript ES6 arrow functions

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony, arrow-functions

Does anyone know how to write an immediate function using ES6 arrow syntax?

Here's the ES3/5 way of doing it:

```
(function () {
   //...
}());
```

I've tried the following but get an `unexpected token` error on the last line.

```
(() => {
  //...
}());
```

You can test this here: http://www.es6fiddle.net/hsb8bgu4/

Comment: Close the grouping before calling -- `})();` http://www.es6fiddle.net/hsb8ot2m/

Comment: This might be a traceur bug (probably related to [this issue](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/issues/457)). It works fine with babel ([repl demo](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true&code=()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%22Yay!%22%0D%0A%7D()%3B))

Comment: Always remember that `function_name `+` ()` ===  `function_caller`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

From the [Arrow functions examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions#Examples),

```
(() => "foobar")() // returns "foobar"
```

So, the function invocation operator should be outside.

```
(() => {
  //...
})();
```

Sample: http://www.es6fiddle.net/hsb8s1sj/

Comment: This way works with regular functions too, and it just makes more sense anyway - wrapping the function itself to make it an expression, then calling that expression. The fact that it also works when you wrap the whole function call is a weird quirk imo, I'm glad this doesn't work with arrows

Answer (score 11):

**Here is my demo codes!**

> Always remember that `function_name`+`()` ===  `function_caller`

```js
/* ES5 */

// normal function

function abc(){
    console.log(`Hello, ES5's function!`);
}
abc();

var abc = function xyz(){
    console.log(`Hello, ES5's function!`);
};
abc();

// named function

var abc = function xyz(){
    console.log(`Hello, ES5's function!`);
}();


// anonymous function
// 1
(function(){
    console.log(`Hello, ES5's IIFE!`);
})();

// 2
(function(){
    console.log(`Hello, ES5's IIFE!`);
}());

// 3

var abc = function(){
    console.log(`Hello, ES5's function!`);
}();


/* ES6 */

// named arrow function
const xyz = () => {
    console.log(`Hello, ES6's Arrow Function!`);
};
xyz();


const xyz = (() => {
    console.log(`Hello, ES6's Arrow Function!`);
})();


// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

/*
const xyz = (() => {
    console.log(`Hello, ES6's Arrow Function!`);
}());
*/

// anonymous arrow function
(() => {
    console.log(`Hello, ES6's Arrow Function!`);
})();
```

[image: Using ES6 Arrow Functions realize IIEF!]

[Immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

```js
let x;

(x = () => {
  console.log(`ES6 ${typeof(x)}`);
})();

// ES6 function

// OR

(() => {
  console.log(`ES6 ${typeof(Symbol)}`);
})();

// ES6 function
```

Comment: "Immediately-invoked function expression" as a term describes a design pattern which has also been referred to as a "self-executing anonymous function."

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example.

To define an arrow function:

```js
const temp = (x)=> {return x+" world";}

// call it as a function
temp("hello") // output: hello world
```

To make an arrow function immediately invoke:

```js
const temp = ((x)=> {return x+" world";})("hello")

// use it as a variable:
console.log(temp); // output: hello world

// a self-invoking function without params:
const temp = (()=> {return "world";})()
```