# How to return a jsx element with an inline switch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to return an element with an inline switch. But I am getting only a empty `<span> </span>`. What am I doing wrong?

```
 getRowTdForHeader: (header: string, entry: response) => {
            return (<span>
                {() => {
                    switch (header) {
                        case "Name":  return entry.name;
                        case "Type": return entry.type;
                        default: return entry.name;
                    }
                } }
            </span>);
        }
```

Result is a empty `span` and if I put a breakpoint at the return, it never goes into the switch statement at all. I'd like to keep it as a in-liner if possible. The switch works fine if I don't inline it btw.

Comment: First, I don't see purpose for `()=>` Second, even switch is not required. You can do `entry[(header || 'name')]`

Comment: @Rajesh How does this work `entry[(header || 'name')]`?

Comment: `entry` is an object and since you are returning property that is same word but different case, `header.toLowercase()` will give you property name. So if header is `Name`, `entry[header.toLowerCase()]` will return `entry['name']`. `|| 'name'`  is the default value. If header is not defined, return `name`. Also my apologies, I forgot `.toLowerCase()`

Comment: @Rajesh Alright thanks. But the header names do not necessarily reflect the property name.

Comment: But will case always have return value only? If yes, I'd suggest to create a map and then just return `entry[map[header]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to wrap the arrow function in parentheses and execute it immediately with a following pair of parentheses.

```
{(() => {
    switch (header) {
                        case "Name":  return entry.name;
                        case "Type": return entry.type;
                        default: return entry.name;
                    }
})()}
```

Comment: This syntax worked. Could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: see  this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138550/immediate-function-using-javascript-es6-arrow-functions

Answer (score 1):

you defined a function but not call it

```
() => {
    switch (header) {
        case "Name":  return entry.name;
        case "Type": return entry.type;
        default: return entry.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I call it?

Comment: as @Vladu answered

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you put the result into a variable and then use it:

```
getRowTdForHeader: (header: string, entry: response) => {
    let str: string;
    switch (header) {
        case "Name":  str = entry.name;
        case "Type": str = entry.type;
        default: str = entry.name;
    }

    return <span> { str } </span>;
}
```

Comment: I guess I could do it this way, but I was curious about the inline functions.

Comment: It feels that using a function in this case is redundant. You have nothing to gain from it.

Comment: My main purpose was to use the switch inside the `<span>` tags. No idea how else I would go about this without a function call?

Comment: Why does the `switch` need to be inside the `<span>`? The conversion between the `header` to a string doesn't even have to happen in this method, you can have a static/global function which does that for you.

Comment: Does not need to be there, but for learning purposes on how I would go about inline functions.

Comment: Alright. Just be careful not to misuse this feature