# Redux-presist - Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-persist

I am learning to use Redux persist so not to lose my store data when refresh the page. I am using custom middleware named logger. I kind of know that this error is because my store is undefined when i'm calling provider but I don't know where I am doing wrong. Please help me understand the issue and resolve it.

```
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const { store, persistor } = () => {
    const store = createStore (
        persistedReducer, 
        applyMiddleware (logger)
    );

    const persistor = persistStore(store)
    return { store, persistor }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}> 
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <App />
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: you need to call function: `const { store, persistor } = (() => { ... })()

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood and resolved my issue.

Comment: Please can you tell me some link containing information about the thing you used

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138550/immediate-function-using-javascript-es6-arrow-functions

Comment: How have u solved @Ketan , Can u plz let me know with code

Answer (score 0):

Check your export and Import of store.

export default

```js
//In store.js file
export default store;

//in App.js

import store from ..[path]
```